# Is there any wrong with this code I wrote for learning switch case test in C

Tags: c

I am learning code using C programming. I wrote a `switch` statement for finding area of rectangle, square and triangle. Could you please let me know what has gone wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int AreaOfSquare(int a)
float AreaOfrectangle(float b, float h)
float AreaOftriangle(float a, float b)
int NoneOfthose()

main(void)
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            AreaOfSquare(5);
            break;
        case 2:
            AreaOfrectangle(6, 5);
            break;
        case 3:
            AreaOftriangle(7, 8);
            break;
        default:
            NoneOfthose();
            printf("Please enter a Valid choice");
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int AreaOfSquare(int a)
{
    int area_s;
    area_s = a * a;
    printf("Area of Square is = %d\n", area_s);
}

float AreaOfrectangle(float b, float h)
{
    float area_r;
    area_r = (b * h) / 2;
    printf("Area of Square is = %f\n", area_r);  
}

float AreaOftriangle(float a, float b)
{
    float area_t;
    area_t = a * b;
    printf("Area of triangle is = %f\n" area_t);
}

int NoneOfthose(void)
{
    printf(" There is nothing to calculate");
}
```

I've made some corrections to the data types declared for each function used to calculate the area.

Comment: Check which calculation is being performed in which function... A bit of a mix-up...

Comment: Look for the compiler errors and fix it. [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/hbJqVb3RW)

Comment: Each function prototype at the top needs a `;` at the end. `main` needs `int` as return type. `float name; name = ...;` is an anti-pattern from old C standards. Use `float name = ...;` instead.

Comment: user21017887, why did you code with `float` and not `double`?

Answer (score 3):

1. There a number of syntax errors.  Missing `;` after the function declaration, missing `,` before area_t.  This tells us that you never compiled the code you shared with us (it's bare minimum to do so before asking for help).  Eliminated the prototypes by moving `main()` to the bottom of the file.
2. `main()` should return an `int`.
3. In `AreaOfrectangle()` your message says Square.  Duplicating code like this, btw, is a hint to refactor your code.  The only difference between your area functions is the number of arguments, the formula used to calculate area the the name of the shape.  For example:

```
void PrintResult(const char *shape, float area) {
    printf("Area of %s is = %f\n", shape, area);
}

// changed return type and argument to float for consistency
// with the other Area functions, but also to avoid having
// to write a PrintResult() for both int and float.
float AreaOfSquare(float a) {
    return a * a;
}

// ...
    float area;
    char *name;
    switch(a) {
        case 1:
            area = AreaOfSquare(5);
            shape = "Square";
            break;
// ...
        default:
            NoneOfthose();
            return 1;
    }
    PrintResult(shape, area);
```

4. Check `scanf()` return value otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized data.
5. All your area functions was declared to return something but didn't, so changed the return type to `void` (but see point 3 above).
6. (not fixed) Consider introducing an `enum` to assign constants to your menu choices, i.e.:

```
enum {
  SQUARE = 1,
  RECTANGLE,
  TRIANGLE
};
```

Then you can use those those constants in your case statements which would be more readable.

7. (not fixed) Consider using `%g` instead of `%f` when printing floating point numbers.  It will remove trailing zeros.
8. (not fixed) Consider using `double` instead of `float`.
9. (not fixed) Your prompt, "Please enter a Valid choice", implies that you want to run this in a loop till a valid choice is made.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void AreaOfSquare(int a) {
    int area_s;
    area_s = a * a;
    printf("Area of square is = %d\n", area_s);
}

void AreaOfrectangle(float b, float h) {
    float area_r;
    area_r = (b * h) / 2;
    printf("Area of rectangle is = %f\n", area_r);
}

void AreaOftriangle(float a, float b) {
    float area_t;
    area_t = a * b;
    printf("Area of triangle is = %f\n", area_t);
}

void NoneOfthose(void) {
    printf(" There is nothing to calculate");
}

int main(void) {
    int a;
    if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
        return 1;
    switch(a) {
        case 1:
            AreaOfSquare(5);
            break;
        case 2:
            AreaOfrectangle(6, 5);
            break;
        case 3:
            AreaOftriangle(7, 8);
            break;
        default:
            NoneOfthose();
            printf("Please enter a Valid choice");
    }
}
```